# Function to display an alert

Tags: javascript, dom

It's a user alert script. It worked in every browser I tested. But the function itself looks very messy/repetitive. Is there any way to make this cleaner?

```
function message(text) {
    var alert = document.createElement('div');
    var alertText = document.createTextNode(text);
    var alertCloseButton = document.createElement('i');
    var buttonText = document.createTextNode('close');
    var shadow = document.createElement('div');

    alert.className = 'alert-text';
    alertCloseButton.className = 'material-icons';
    alertCloseButton.id = 'close-alert';
    alertCloseButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'function() { var a = this.parentNode; var s = a.parentNode; s.parentNode.removeChild(s)}');
    alertCloseButton.onclick = function() { var a = this.parentNode; var s = a.parentNode; s.parentNode.removeChild(s) };
    alertCloseButton.appendChild(buttonText);
    alert.appendChild(alertCloseButton);
    alert.appendChild(alertText);
    shadow.className = 'shadow';
    shadow.appendChild(alert);

    document.body.appendChild(shadow);
}
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    message('Button clicked');
});
```

Here's the code working: https://jsfiddle.net/3aouyfz7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

It's true that using objects can become messy after a while. That's why [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) are so powerful in this situation.

I would highly advise to avoid using `parentNode` when attempting to remove HTML, you may unintentionally remove something in the future if you decide to make your alert HTML more complex.

To solve this, create a container element that is accessible by your onclose method.

Also, I would also advise to not overwrite existing objects. Why not name alert to something else?

Don't add onclick events directly in the HTML, it's messy.

### Solution:

```
function message(text) {

  const container = document.createElement("div");

  const onClose = ()=>container.remove();

  container.innerHTML = `
   <div class="shadow">
      <div class="alert-text">
        <i id="close-alert" class="material-icons">close</i>
        ${text}
      </div>
   </div>
  `;

  document.body.appendChild(container);

  document
    .querySelector('i#close-alert')
    .addEventListener("click", onClose);
}
```

### Working Example:

```js
function message(text) {

  const container = document.createElement("div");

  const onClose = ()=>container.remove();

  container.innerHTML = `
   <div class="shadow">
      <div class="alert-text">
        <i id="close-alert" class="material-icons">close</i>
        ${text}
      </div>
   </div>
  `;
  
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  
  document
    .querySelector('i#close-alert')
    .addEventListener("click", onClose);
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  message('Button clicked');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.shadow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 98;
}

.alert-text {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 2.5em;
  min-height: 10%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.alert-text i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.alert-text i:hover {
  color: #444
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>

  <h3>Page content</h3>
  <button>alert</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the clean up, i've learned a lot from your answer.